# how to display year in drop down using html?

Tags: html

Below is html code I wrote. how do i edit it in html such that the word year appears on the drop down box for it? So far it displays 2020.

```
<select class="" name="year" required>
            <option value="2020">2020</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Hi, You can use Jquery Datepicker UI plug-in , Please use below link
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike input elements, select does not have a "placeholder" so you have to add it in as option, but if you don't want users to select it you can place the disabled attribute.

```html
<select class="" name="year" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select Year</option>
      <option value="2020">2020</option>
      <option value="2019">2019</option>
      <option value="2018">2018</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
      <option value="2016">2016</option>
      <option value="2015">2015</option>
      <option value="2014">2014</option>
      <option value="2013">2013</option>
      <option value="2012">2012</option>
      <option value="2011">2011</option>
    </select>
```